# How to (error free) iterate values of variable jquery array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple PHP project that can create a json array of data values to be forwarded to a jQuery script. For example such an array would look like this: `[3,94,83,141]`. I want to use those values to change the visibility of rows in a table. But I run into errors.

Assume `rArray = [3,94,83,141]`

First method:

```
    $.each(rArray, function (index, value) {
        $("#ready_foods tbody td[data-foodid=" + value + "]").parent().toggle();
    });
```

console error: `Uncaught TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for "length" in "[3,94,83,141]"`

2nd method:

```
    $(rArray).each(function (index, value) {
        $("#ready_foods tbody td[data-foodid=" + value + "]").parent().toggle();
    });
```

console error:
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [3,94,83,141]`

I've tried expressing the data values as an object with similar results.

The only way to get expected results is to use the actual array (e.g., `[3,94,83,141]`) instead of the variable name `rArray`.

What am I missing?

Edit:
Yes, it's from PHP\Symfony.
Controller snippet; `'rte' => json_encode($rte),`

template snippet: `<div class="rte" style="display:none;">{{ rte }}</div>`

No change to results.

Tried `var rArray = JSON.parse(($(".rte").text())).slice(1, -1);` but that took off the `[` and `]` of the array!

Comment: You're not setting `rArray` to an array, you're setting it to a string. Your actual code must be `rArray = "[3,94,83,141]";`

Comment: if this is coming from PHP, show how you're transfering the values from PHP to JS.

Comment: I suspect you forgot to call `JSON.parse()` after you fetched the data from PHP.

Comment: The error is where you assign the array to JS, you actually assign string such as `rArray="[3,94]"` instead of `rArray=[3,94]`.

Comment: @skobaljic How, then, should the variable `rArray` be assigned the unquoted array?

Answer (score 0):

The culprit in this case was `'rte' => json_encode($rte)`. Replaced that with `'rte' => $rte` and errors vanished.